# Computing glm coefficient matrix , bias and mean square error

Tags: r, matrix, glm

I have the following code using R:

```
x0 <- matrix(rnorm(100,1))
x <- as.matrix(cbind("Intercept"=1, x0))
n <- dim(x0)[[1]]
z <- cbind(rep(1,n),x0)
p <- dim(x0)[[2]]+1

for(i in 1:n) {
  gstart <- glm(y~x0,family=binomial)$coef
}
```

I want to compute the estimates of the previous generalized linear model in  `n` samples and create  a matrix of estimates for the `n` instances then computing  `bias` and `mean square error`, where the matrix of parameters are given by the following code:

```
n=100 #is the number of samples
parameter.mat<-cbind(rep(2,n),rep(2,n))
```

Comment: Should `y` be defined somewhere, and `x` and `p` aren't used and `n` is defined twice?  This is a little confusing

Answer (score 1):

***I think*** that you are wanting to examine the difference between the coefficients returned by `glm` and the average non-parametric `bootstrap` coefficients. The example below, first gives a way using the [`boot package`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html), and then using a loop (similar to your question)

```
# some example data - set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),  x = rnorm(100))

# samples
n <- 1000

# glm estimates
mod <- glm(y ~ x, family="binomial", data=dat)$coef


# alternative method using boot package -----------------------------------
library(boot)

# function to extract model coefficients
f <- function(dat, i) glm(y ~ x, family="binomial", data=dat[i, ])$coef

# run bootstrap
set.seed(1)
boot(dat, f, R=n)  

# manual bootstrap  - sample with replacement -----------------------------
out <- vector("list", length=n)

for(i in 1:n) {
     newdat <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), , T), ]
     out[[i]] <- glm(y ~ x, family="binomial", data=newdat)$coef
     }

# matrix of bootstrap coefficients
bc <- do.call("rbind", out)

# bootstrap means
bc.mn <- colMeans(bc)
bias <- mod - bc.mn
```